# Controlling high torque servo motors with Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, servomotor, torque

I need to control 10 **Standard Servo Motors** *(operating at 4.8-7V/300mA-1A/2.5kg-5kg torque)* in my project. I'm using RPi as my processor and I was looking for a servo driver. I came across PCA9685 16-ch 12-bit servo driver from adafruit, But it can only operate at 5.5V maximum. also, each standard servo can consume upto 1.5A current and PCA9685 board cannot handle that.
***Are there any other servo drivers available for handling 5-7V and 1-1.5Amp per channel?***
(Powering the servos separately is an option but if any board is available makes it easier for me)

Comment: You might like to try this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/518865/how-to-interface-uart-servo-lx-224hv